# Смена изображения при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

Есть задача -нужен блок, где можно будет прокрутить длинное изображение (или несколько стоящих в ряд) горизонтальным скроллом влево-вправо. Скролл должен начинаться с середины. 
На данный момент реализовал так:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wrap ul {
  min-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.wrap li img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>изображение 1</li>
    <li>изображение 2</li>
    <li>изображение 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Нашел в интернете, что с помощью `$(selector).scrollleft(position)` можно поставить изначальную позицию скролла на середину, но не удалось это прописать. Версткой недавно занимаюсь, в скриптах смыслю пока что мало, прошу совета) Так же попутно есть вопрос, есть ли кроссбраузерные решения для изменения внешности скроллбара? А то пишут через `css` только на `IE` работает

Comment: Побывали загружать внутрь `iframe`?

Comment: "кроссбраузерные решения для изменения внешности скроллбара" - это использовать `div` со своими кастомными скролами, полностью сделанными Вашими ручками.

Comment: iframe еще не пробовал, посмотрю как с ним

Answer (score 2):

***Тухленко получилось***, лучше бы программно вычислить длину изображения

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wrapper').scrollLeft(400);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: 230px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">

    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам в помощь javascript.
На чистом css можно сделать подобное через псевдокласс :focus или :active на кнопку, а к псевдоклассу привязать анимацию @keyframes, которая будет двигать картинку 
при этом должен быть body: {overflow-x: hidden;} чтобы горизонтальная прокрутка была спрятана, ее также можно активировать через псевдокласс :focus или :active если столь необходимо будет.

Answer (score 0):

Уже была похожая тема(моя кстати) - [Вертикальный слайдер. Как сделать карусель?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821619/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C). Используя ответ @рони, вот пример на нативном

```js
document.querySelector(".carousel-module").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var parent = document.querySelector(".img-container"),
    first = parent.querySelector(".item-img"),
    last = parent.querySelector(".item-img:last-child");
  if (e.target.classList.contains("arrow-left")) {
    parent.appendChild(first)
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains("arrow-right")) {
    parent.insertBefore(last, first)
  }
});
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0
}

.carousel-module {
  margin-top: 100px;
  min-width: 660px;
  text-align: center
}

.img-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden
}

.arrow-left,
.arrow-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s
}

.arrow-left {
  border-width: 50px 20px 50px 0;
  border-color: transparent #000000 transparent transparent
}

.arrow-right {
  border-width: 50px 0 50px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000000
}

.arrow-left:active,
.arrow-right:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8)
}

.item-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .7s;
  -o-transition: .7s;
  transition: .7s
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-530%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-530%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-530%, -50%)
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-410%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-410%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-410%, -50%)
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-290%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-290%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-290%, -50%)
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-170%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-170%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-170%, -50%)
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(70%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(70%, -50%);
  transform: translate(70%, -50%)
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(7) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(190%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(190%, -50%);
  transform: translate(190%, -50%)
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(8) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(310%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(310%, -50%);
  transform: translate(310%, -50%)
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(9) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(430%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(430%, -50%);
  transform: translate(430%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-module">
  <div class="arrow-left"></div>
  <div class="img-container"><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/EF5350/000000.png&amp;text=image" alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/BA68C8/000000.png&amp;text=image" alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/7986CB/000000.png&amp;text=image"
      alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/64B5F6/000000.png&amp;text=image" alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/4DB6AC/000000.png&amp;text=image" alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/81C784/000000.png&amp;text=image"
      alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/AED581/000000.png&amp;text=image" alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/DCE775/000000.png&amp;text=image" alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/FB8C00/000000.png&amp;text=image"
      alt="" /></div>
  <div class="arrow-right"></div>
</div>
```