# Вертикальный слайдер. Как сделать карусель?

Tags: javascript

Обращаюсь к адептам nativeJS. Прошу Вашей помощи. Простой вертикальный слайдер. Не пойму как сделать из него карусель? Была мысль использовать shift/push. Но чего-то туплю я. Знаний не хватает. Подскажите дурачку, кому не трудно. Интересно на чистом JS.

```js
document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target.classList.contains('arrow-top')) {
   Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('item-img')).map(el=>{el.style.top=(parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).top)-200)+"px"})
  }
  if(e.target.classList.contains('arrow-bottom')) {
   Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('item-img')).map(el=>el.style.top=(parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).top)+200)+"px")
  }
})
```

```css
*,*:after,*:before{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;margin:0;outline:0}
.wrapper{width:300px;margin:100px auto}
.wrap-img{position:relative;height:200px;width:300px;border:2px solid #000;margin:10px 0;overflow:hidden}
.arrow-top,.arrow-bottom{height:20px;width:300px;border-style:solid;cursor:pointer;transition:1s}
.arrow-top{border-width:0 150px 20px 150px;border-color:transparent transparent #424242 transparent;}
.arrow-bottom{border-width:20px 150px 0 150px;border-color:#424242 transparent transparent transparent;}
.arrow-top:active,.arrow-bottom:active{transform:scale(0.8)}
.item-img{position:absolute;max-width:100%;left:0;transition:.3s}
.item-img:nth-of-type(1){top:-400px}
.item-img:nth-of-type(2){top:-200px}
.item-img:nth-of-type(3){top:0}
.item-img:nth-of-type(4){top:200px}
.item-img:nth-of-type(5){top:400px}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow-top"></div>
  <div class="wrap-img"><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/F44336/fff.png" alt=""/><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/5C6BC0/fff.png" alt=""/><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/03A9F4/fff.png" alt=""/><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/4CAF50/fff.png" alt=""/><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/FF9800/fff.png" alt=""/></div>
  <div class="arrow-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для начала надо ввести индекс текущей картинки, при быстром переключении сбивается расположение. И обычно перемещают контейнер со слайдами, а не каждый слайд по отдельности, и делают это не position, а transform translate (намного выше производительность). А что вы хотели делать на js, с помощью shift/push я не понял. Добавить слайды чтобы зациклить? Я добавил бы по одному слайду в начало и в конец, и после окончания анимации на него переключался бы без анимации на первый/последний.

Comment: shift/push - думал сделать массив и при каждом клике, удалять\вставлять в очередь. Но это не понадобилось. Ответ ниже это демонстрирует. И да при быстром переключении, position будет сбиваться, так как проверок я не делал. Как можно быстрее пример накляпал. Просто каркас. Суть он отразил.

Comment: В принципе все можно было сделать на CSS-- input[type="radio"], ниже коде управляемый контейнер, один родитель и т.д. Я ж написал интересно на JS. Изучаю я его )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вариант ...

```js
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var parent = document.querySelector(".wrap-img"),
    first = parent.querySelector(".item-img"),
    last = parent.querySelector(".item-img:last-child");
  if (e.target.classList.contains("arrow-top")) {
    parent.appendChild(first);
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains("arrow-bottom")) {
    parent.insertBefore(last, first);
  }
});
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto
}

.wrap-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

.arrow-top,
.arrow-bottom {
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  border-style: solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s
}

.arrow-top {
  border-width: 0 150px 20px 150px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #424242 transparent;
}

.arrow-bottom {
  border-width: 20px 150px 0 150px;
  border-color: #424242 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.arrow-top:active,
.arrow-bottom:active {
  transform: scale(0.8)
}

.item-img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transition: .3s
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: -400px
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: -200px
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 0
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: 200px
}

.item-img:nth-of-type(5) {
  top: 400px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow-top"></div>
  <div class="wrap-img"><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/F44336/fff.png" alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/5C6BC0/fff.png" alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/03A9F4/fff.png" alt="" /><img
      class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/4CAF50/fff.png" alt="" /><img class="item-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/FF9800/fff.png" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="arrow-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Рони, благодарю. Запомню.

Answer (score 0):

```
.item-img:nth-of-type(1){left:-400px}
.item-img:nth-of-type(2){left:-200px}
.item-img:nth-of-type(3){left:0}
.item-img:nth-of-type(4){left:200px}
.item-img:nth-of-type(5){left:400px}
```

Ну и стрелки по бокам, так нет?

Comment: благодарю за ответ, но к вопросу это не относится